# simple example of implement camunda integrate with nodejs

Tags: node.js, bpmn, camunda

I want execute below bpmn diagram in camunda and use it in my application that implement with node js

[image]

I read and implement this example :

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/sdk-js/nodejs

and I can connect to camunda engine-rest  and call camunda api like this :

```
var CamSDK = require('camunda-bpm-sdk-js');

var camClient = new CamSDK.Client({
  mock: false,
  // the following URL does not need authentication,
  // but the tradeof is that some requests will fail
  // e.g.: some filters use the reference to the user performing the request
  apiUri: 'http://localhost:8080/engine-rest'
});

var processDefinitionService  = new camClient.resource('process-definition');
var processInstanceService    = new camClient.resource('process-instance');
var filterService             = new camClient.resource('filter');
var deploymentService         = new camClient.resource('deployment');
```

but I dont know how to implement a simple project like above bpmn and execute it and use it in nodejs application with rest api,if possible I want a full sample for this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use nodejs to execute tasks in the workflow you could use the [external task pattern](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/process-engine/external-tasks/). A proof of concept of a nodejs external worker can be found on https://github.com/nikku/camunda-worker-node. But please node this was only for demonstration purpose and may not work with the latest camunda version. But the concepts should still be the same.

The camunda-bpm-sdk-js is basically a client for the [Camunda REST API](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/reference/rest/). With it you could also query also for external tasks or user tasks and complete them.